# Django Rest Framework - serializers.SlugRelatedField does not return field value

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have the following `Car` model in my `Django Rest Framework` project:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Car(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='cars', on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
```

As you can see, the `Car` model has a foreignkey relationship with the built-in `User` model. The field is called `driver`.
Now, using the serializer class I also wanted to print out the username of the driver. Therefore, I used `serializers.SlugRelatedField` like this:

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='username')
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'username']
```

But in the JSON output I can not see the username value:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "BMW"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Audi"
    }
]
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Can you try this in your serializer : username = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='django_user__username')

Comment: no, it does not worked. same json output as mentioned above

Comment: why not use a `SerializerMethodField` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a custom field SlugField can't be use as from the [documents](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#slugfield)

> A RegexField that validates the input against a URL matching pattern.
> Expects fully qualified URLs of the form http:///.
>
> Corresponds to django.db.models.fields.URLField. Uses Django's
> django.core.validators.URLValidator for validation.
>
> Signature: URLField(max_length=200, min_length=None,
> allow_blank=False)

so it doesn't accept `slug_field` as an argument and this field only use to do regex for `urls`

This is how you would create a custom field to return from serializer:

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.SerializerMethodField() # custom serializer method

    def get_username(self, obj):
        return obj.driver.username

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'username']
```